# The Real Part of an Imaginary Number

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Can any real number be the real part of an imaginary number?

Can a mathematical expression which is equivalent to any real number be used as the real part of an imaginary number? If a series converges to a real number, can that series be used as the real part of an imaginary number?

Comment: hint: $f(x)=x+i$

Comment: Consider how you construct the set of complex numbers.

Comment: "The real part of an imaginary number" is $0$.  The real part of a complex number is any real number; the imaginary part of a complex number is also any real number.  Assuming you meant to use "complex" in place of "imaginary", the answers are all "yes".

Comment: I find all of these comments very helpful.